# put a text "select option" in dropdown and later clean the dropdown in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a dropdown and I want to have a first blank element by default something like "select an option", and when the user selects a dropdown element this first field disappears. later with the help of a setInterval I am trying to clean my dropdown to not select any option and to see the dropdown as I was from the beginning. How can I achieve it? This is my code.

```
 //templates/home/home.component.html

<select  [(ngModel)]='myselect' >
 <option [value]="" selected  >select and option</option>
 <option  *ngFor='let option of test' [value]="option.id">  
 {{option.nombre}}</option>
</select>

 //components/home/home.component.ts

 title = 'app';
 myselect:any;
 test:any= [{"id": "1", "nombre":"pedro" },{"id": "2", 
 "nombre":"yeison" }];
 ngOnInit() {
   this.timeoutFun();
 }

 timeoutFun() {
 setTimeout(function(){
 //clear my dropdown 
 this.myselect=""; 
 }, 5000);
}
```

this is my code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n8x7xo?file=src/app/templates/home/home.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think the below is what you want. You need an `*ngUf` in the option that is to disappear and some property bound to it that will trigger it to go away or reappear. Also, in your setTimeout, since you aren't using an arrow function, you are losing the scope of your component, so when you update those values, they aren't being applied to the instance of the component as intended.

> //templates/home/home.component.html

```
<h1>This is home component</h1>
<button (click)="open()">Open Modal</button>
<br>
<select  (ngModel)='myselect' (change)="updateOptions()" >
  <option *ngIf="foo" [value]="" selected  >select and option</option>
  <option  *ngFor='let option of test' [value]="option.id">  
 {{option.nombre}}</option>
</select>
```

> //components/home/home.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from '../../services/app.service';
import { ModalModel } from '../../models/modal.model';

declare let $: any;


@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: '../../templates/home/home.component.html',
  providers: [AppService]

})
export class HomeComponent {
  title = 'app';
  foo = true;

  modelData = new ModalModel();
    constructor(
        private _service: AppService
    ){}
    myselect:any;
    test:any= [{"id": "1", "nombre":"pedro" },{"id": "2", "nombre":"yeison" }];
    ngOnInit() {
      this.timeoutFun();
    }
    timeoutFun() {
        setTimeout(() =>{
        //clear my dropdown 
        this.myselect=""; 
        this.foo = true;
        alert('here');
      }, 5000);
    }
    open() 
    {
      this.modelData.header = 'This is my dynamic HEADER from Home component';
      this.modelData.body = 'This is my dynamic BODY from Home component';
      this.modelData.footer = 'This is my dynamic footer from Home component';
      this._service.open(this.modelData);
    }
updateOptions() {
  this.foo = false;
}



}
```

Comment: thanks ... but I want to ask you something, there is some way to not use the variable "foo" and the second is that initially the dropdown has no text, it is blank.

Comment: I have updated your example: https://angular-dtjgme.stackblitz.io This just keys off the value of `myselect` so doesn't need `foo`. You need to pull in `ReactiveFormsModule` and update the html and ts files as in the example. Hope this helps!

Comment: It's just what I need! ... excuse my ignorance, but how do I see your new code? I only see the result. thank you!